# Prove a limit by definition given another limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

**If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)\over x-a}=L$, for some $L\neq \pm\infty$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=0$**

My proof goes as follows:

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)\over x-a}=L$, by the definition:

Given $\varepsilon>0, ~\exists ~\delta>0 ~||x-a|<\delta \implies \left|{f(x)\over x-a}-L\right|<\varepsilon $

Then:
$\left|{f(x)\over x-a}-L\right|<\varepsilon$

$\left|{f(x)}-L(x-a)\right|<\varepsilon|x-a|$

$\left|{f(x)}-L(x-a)\right|<\varepsilon|x-a|<\varepsilon\delta$

$\left|{f(x)}-L(x-a)\right|<\varepsilon\delta$

By using the triangle inequality $|u|-|v|\leq |u-v|$:

$|{f(x)}|-|L(x-a)|\leq\left|{f(x)}-L(x-a)\right|<\varepsilon\delta$

$|{f(x)}|-|L(x-a)|<\varepsilon\delta$

$|{f(x)}|<\varepsilon\delta+|L(x-a)|$

$|{f(x)}|<\varepsilon\delta+|L(x-a)|<\varepsilon\delta+|L|\delta$

$|{f(x)}|<\varepsilon\delta+|L|\delta$

$|{f(x)}|<(\varepsilon+|L|)\delta$

Then, given $\varepsilon'>0$, choose $\delta ={\varepsilon'\over\varepsilon+|L|}$, we have:

$|{f(x)}|<\varepsilon'$

Therefore, since $|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-0|<\varepsilon'$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=0$

Comment: I would chose $\epsilon = 1$ and the corresponding $\delta_0$. Then, along the same lines as your proof, you get $|f(x)|<(1+|L|)|x-a|$ for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta_0$. Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and set $\delta = \min\left\{\frac{\epsilon}{1+|L|},\delta_0\right\}$. Then if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Hint: try to mimic the proof of the theorem about the product of two limits but where one limit is of the function $\dfrac{f(x)}{x-a}$ and the another one is $x-a$.

Comment: @CarlosJiménez , Could then I proved just by considering $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)\over x-a}\cdot (x-a)=60\cdot 0=0$?

Comment: Just a typo correction, instead of 60 I mean $L$

Answer (score 1):

Here, lim x-->a
|f(x)/(x-a)| ≤|L|
=> |f(X)|≤|L(X-a)|
Now,lim x-->a |L(x-a)| =0
lim x-->a , |f(X)|=0
=> lim x-->a ,f(X)=0 (proved)